# Magento / PayPal Partial Refunds, Refunding Whole Order

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-standard

We are using **Magento ver. 1.7.0.2** and have an issue when processing partial refunds via Magento.

When processing a refund for 1 item, when 3 items are purchased, Magento sends a message to PayPal of the refund though PayPal sends a message back to Magento stating that the order has been refunded, this puts the whole order of 3 items back in stock. The correct amount is refunded though.

**Using PayPal Payments Standard.**

Does anyone have experience with this?

Stuck.

Comment: Anyone come across this issue before?